# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Deployment folder structure

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, publish, visual-studio-publish

When publishing an ASP.NET Core Web App, all dlls in the project depedencies are generated directly under root folder - see the screenshot below. Thank you.

Is there a way to move them to a seperate folder, like bin folder in ASP.NET Framework? I assume lots of people have this same question, but I can't seem find the related posted. Did I miss something?

[Please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqCQ7.png)

Comment: Check you Publish target location and the build output path.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It seems I misled you. The problem is all the DLLs are generated in the root of the published target location. I hope they can be in a separate folder under the root like bin folder in ASP.NET. Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Projects output path is set on the projects properties. Right click project name on the solution explorer and select properties. Select build on the right side panel and check the output path. This defines where the project will store the .Dll it creates.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Yep, the output setting defines the output path for the whole project. The issue is in the output folder, I want those dlls from dependencies to save in a separate folder rather than directly under the root of the output.